# How to insert links containing spaces?

Tags: support

I have failed to insert this link into comments:

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx#Implementing the dispose pattern for a derived class
```

Here is how it looks like:

- as text: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx#Implementing the dispose pattern for a derived class
- as markdown element [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx#Implementing the dispose pattern for a derived class).

---

Edit: I just discovered this link isn't actually leading where I want unless "Implementing the ..." link is already clicked on that page.

Comment: Links cannot contain space. Like this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx#Implementing-the-dispose-pattern-for-a-derived-class **Note:** spaces replaced by hyphens

Comment: Which browser are you using? Any sane browser should use `%20` when copying from the URL bar.

Comment: Or the documentation have provided the icon next to that paragraph for linking to it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2 Similarly, many of the websites provide this feature.

Comment: You just got the URL wrong, it is `#Anchor_1`.  Looks like an anchor too when you hover over the section title.

Comment: @HansPassant the links in the right-side bar (*IN THIS ARTICLE*) is where OP got it from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the **white spaces** with **%20** in the link

**Sample Link:**

```
[Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx#Implementing%20the%20dispose%20pattern%20for%20a%20derived%20class)
```

**Rendered output:**

[Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx#Implementing%20the%20dispose%20pattern%20for%20a%20derived%20class)

**Update:** As [suggested by Tushar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343377/how-to-insert-links-containing-spaces#comment445158_343378) **%20** not helps on the OP's current question to navigate a specific place.
Replacing the white space with hyphen (-) is supports to navigate the specific paragraph as per the OP's question.

**Sample Link:**

```
[Test1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx#Implementing-the-dispose-pattern-for-a-derived-class)
```

**Rendered output:**

[Test1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx#Implementing-the-dispose-pattern-for-a-derived-class)

Comment: Doesn't work. OP want to link to specific paragraph on that page. [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx#Implementing-the-dispose-pattern-for-a-derived-class)

Comment: Is it Miscrosoft bug then? They didn't generate URL displayed in the address bar properly? P.S.: I am not web-programmer.

Comment: @Sinatr No. I guess, OP is trying to create the URL manually. MS has provided icon next to it to link to that paragraph. Check my [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343377/how-to-insert-links-containing-spaces#comment445168_343377)

Comment: @Tushar, thanks for explanation. I didn't though address bar url could be something useless (what is a purpose of showing it like this?), but I recall I've seen this somewhere already coupled with "generate proper link to that page" function. I shouldn't complain and must learn instead.